# Combining multiple source language documentations into a single Javadoc JAR

Tags: gradle, javadoc, groovydoc, kdoc

If I have a project that has `java`, `groovy`, and `kotlin` plugins applied with code written in each, how do I create (and should I) create a single `javadoc.jar` distribution with all of the code documentation?

The `java` plugin gives me the `javadoc` class, the `groovy` plugin gives me the `groovydoc` task, but these do not seem to cooperate.

How do I "merge" this documentation into a single cohesive artifact?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

On the java+groovy side you can do

```
groovydoc.source 'src/main/java'
```

and only run the `groovydoc` task. The only drawback is that you are going to get the groovydoc formatting for all your classes.

Creating the javadoc JAR then becomes

```
task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
    description "An archive of the JavaDocs for Maven Central"
    classifier "javadoc"
    from groovydoc
}
```